# Sequelize - Acceptable bulkCreate Format

Tags: json, express, sequelize.js

I have an issue with my bulkCreate method where the values in my array are not being passed to the bulkCreate method, despite being sent in the proper (or what I believe it to be) JSON format. Could it be the fact that the stored variable is adding '' around the objects?

**Here is the array and object setting code:**

```
return models.User.findAll({
                where: {
                    email: { $or: userEmails}
                }
            }).then(function(user){
                console.log('Member is triggered');
                console.log(user);

                for(var key in user){
                    memberAssociation.push("{ userId: " + user[key].userId + ", memberEmail: " + user[key].email + ", organizationId: " + user[key].organizationId + "}");


                 }

                    console.log('Here is the array ' + memberAssociation); 
})
```

**Outputted `console.log`:**

```
Here is the array { userId: 126, memberEmail: dsfdf@st.com, organizationId: 1},{ userId: 127, memberEmail: sdfsdf@4iof.com, organizationId: 1}
```

**Then sent as a bulkCreate:**

```
.then(function(member){
                console.log(memberAssociation);
                return models.Member.bulkCreate(memberAssociation).then(function(member){
                    console.log(member);
                    console.log('New member')
                    res.send('Success')
                });
```

**Outputted (member):**

```
[ '{ userId: 126, memberEmail: dsfdf@st.com, organizationId: 1}',
  '{ userId: 127, memberEmail: sdfsdf@4iof.com, organizationId: 1}' ]
```

**SQL:**

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `member` (`member_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (NULL,'2017-03-06 07:36:57','2017-03-06 07:36:57'),(NULL,'2017-03-06 07:36:57','2017-03-06 07:36:57');
```

**Here is my full POST route:**

```
  return models.User.findAll({
                where: {
                    email: { $or: userEmails}
                }
            }).then(function(user){
                console.log('Member is triggered');
                console.log(user);

                for(var key in user){
                    memberAssociation.push("{ userId: " + user[key].userId + ", memberEmail: " + user[key].email + ", organizationId: " + user[key].organizationId + "}");
                }

                console.log('Here is the array ' + memberAssociation);

            }).then(function(member){
                console.log(memberAssociation);
                return models.Member.bulkCreate(memberAssociation).then(function(member){
                    console.log(member);
                    console.log('New member')
                    res.send('Success')
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when you perform `memberAssociation.push("...")` you add `String` to your `memberAssociation` array at every iteration instead object. You should push objects every time

```
memberAssociation.push({
    userId: user[key].userId,
    memberEmail: user[key].email,
    organizationId: user[key].organizationId
});
```

And then you could perform `bulkCreate` with above created array, just like you did in your code. The [`documentation`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance) says that the `records` parameter of `bulkCreate` is an array of objects:

> List of objects (key/value pairs) to create instances from

Comment: Thanks for catching my obvious flaw. Worked perfectly.